# "Safe" memory management

Tags: c, error-handling, memory-management

In order to concisify the handling of a failed call to `malloc`, `realloc`, or `calloc`, I have made a few files to dictate "safe" memory management. This is part of my project `stac`, so the prefix will appear in the following code snippets. Further, I have made the decision to use `snake_case` as opposed to standard `camelCase`.

What I hope to get out of this, and questions I have: are these functions in bad practice? Is there a different way I should be handling failed calls to memory allocators? And is there anything particularly wrong with the code I have written?

### safe_mem.c

```
#include "safe_mem.h"

void* safe_malloc(size_t size){
    void* memory = malloc(size);

    if(memory == NULL){
        free(memory);
        runtime_error("failed to allocate memory.");
    }

    return memory;
}

void* safe_calloc(size_t num, size_t size){
    void* memory = calloc(num, size);

    if(memory == NULL){
        free(memory);
        runtime_error("failed to allocate memory.");
    }

    return memory;
}

void* safe_realloc(void* ptr, size_t size){
    void* memory = realloc(ptr, size);

    if(memory == NULL){
        free(memory);
        runtime_error("failed to reallocate memory.");
    }

    return memory;
}
```

### safe_mem.h

```
#ifndef STAC_SAFE_MEM
#define STAC_SAFE_MEM
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "error.h"

void* safe_malloc(size_t);
void* safe_calloc(size_t, size_t);
void* safe_realloc(void*, size_t);
#endif
```

### error.c

```
#include "error.h"

void make_error(char* type, char* message){
    eprintf("%s error: %s\n", type, message);
}

void fatal_error(char* type, char* message, int exit_code){
    make_error(type, message);
    exit(exit_code);
}

void runtime_error(char* message){
    fatal_error("Runtime", message, STATUS_RUNTIME_ERROR);
}

void generic_error(char* message){
    fatal_error("Generic", message, STATUS_GENERIC_ERROR);
}
```

### error.h

```
#ifndef STAC_ERROR
#define STAC_ERROR
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define eprintf(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#define STATUS_OKAY (0)
#define STATUS_RUNTIME_ERROR (1)
#define STATUS_GENERIC_ERROR (-1)

void make_error(char*, char*);
void fatal_error(char*, char*, int);

void runtime_error(char*);
void generic_error(char*);

#endif
```

Comment: I don't see the point in `free`ing memory that couldn't be allocated in all your allocation calls - Although `free`ing a NULL pointer doesn't normally hurt, it also doesn't do *anything*

Comment: @tofro hah, that's a good point... D'oh :p

Comment: What's "standard" about camelCase?  I don't think there's any camelCase in `namespace std`...

Comment: I dislike the name "safe" - that's only the case if exiting the process is somehow safer than checking for `NULL` - and that's patently not the case for many programs.  `malloc_or_die()` (and similar) would be much more honest!

Comment: @TobySpeight I've never looked deeply into case convention in C, but I rather assumed it to be like C++. Apparently not. As for your second point, I don't see any alternative other than exiting the program. How could one recover from a memory shortage in a program?

Comment: Your *realloc* call is somewhat **worse** than the original - The original at least leaves the already allocated memory intact in case of reallocation failure - yours just returns NULL and creates a sort of *logical* memory leak.  Your call should return the original memory in case of failure (obviously, you need to return the potential error in a different way as you do now, then). If something is called `safe_...`, I would expect a better handling of errors over the original calls.

Comment: @tofro again, how would one deal with a lack of memory, if the memory is needed for the program to function?

Comment: One of the pitfalls of the original `realloc` is that if you use it naively (`x = realloc (x, 1000);`),  you'll lose the pointer to valid memory in the error case because it's changed to NULL, thus create a memory leak when memory is tight anyways. A safe realloc should try to work around this and not allow such a naive use. Proposal: `err_type safe_realloc (void **ptr, size)` and only return non-0 if `realloc` didn't fail with `ptr` changed to the new memory, otherwise `ptr` left alone. Thus you can at least save what you have so far instead of losing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> are these functions in bad practice?

I would say not, as long as the original functions they are wrapping have the same function signature to allow their replacement.

> is there anything particularly wrong with the code I have written?

Allocating 0 bytes may return `NULL`, which does not indicate Out-of-memory.
Same for `calloc()`, `realloc()`.

```
void* memory = malloc(size);
// if(memory == NULL){
if(memory == NULL && size > 0){
```

No point in calling `free(memory)` after `if(memory == NULL)`

```
if(memory == NULL){
  //  free(memory);
```

With `eprintf(...)`, consider passing `__FUNC__`, `__LINE__` of the error source to aid in debugging.  Or at least create unique error messages.

```
void* safe_malloc(size_t size){
   runtime_error("failed to malloc memory.");

void* safe_calloc(size_t num, size_t size){
    runtime_error("failed to calloc memory.");
```

In a couple places, use `const` to allow wider application of the functions that are not changing the referenced data.

```
// void make_error(char* type, char* message){
void make_error(const char* type, const char* message){
```

I am not a fan of your name-space choices for `error.h` which includes `eprintf,
 STATUS_OKAY, STATUS_GENERIC_ERROR, make_error, ...`  If I say these used in other ..c files how would I be guided back to `error.h/error.c` as their origin?  Although a bit verbose, I prefer `error_printf, ERROR_STATUS_GENERIC,...`

Minor: `#include <stdio.h>` need not be in `safe_mem.h` nor `#include <stdlib.h>` in `error.h`.  `error.c` *should* have `#include <stdlib.h>` as it calls `exit()`.  `error.c` should not rely on `error.h` including that.  Similar issues for `safe_mem.c`

---

From a *design* standpoint, I would also include `void safe_free(void *)` as the functionality of these *safe* functions may expand and require that even if it present does nothing.  It makes `safe_...()` symmetric.

Comment: I used `STATUS` as a specifier. You would suggest changing the specifier to `ERROR`, so wouldn't `ERROR_GENERIC` be a better name?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Yes.

Answer (score 5):

- Only `#include` what you need. `safe_mem.h` doesn't require any file it includes. On the other hand, `safe_mem.c` does require `error.h` and `stdlib.h`.

  Notice that where `stdlib.h` is included is important. The client shouldn't care whether `safe_mem.c` implementation depends on `stdlib.h` or not. If it is exposed through the `safe_mem.h`, then changing `safe_mem.c` may require you to fix `safe_mem.h` and recompile anything which depends on it.

  Along the same line, I recommend to move `#include <stdio.h>` `#define eprintf` to `error.c` (unless there is a compelling reason to export this name), and drop `#include <stdlib.h>`.
- <strike>`safe_realloc` is not really safe, because it will lead to memory leaks on `realloc` failure.</strike> Please disregard.
- Bind `*` to the variable, not to the type:

  ```
  void *safe_malloc(....);
  ```

Comment: The program is done in on allocation failure, so not freeing memory would be immaterial anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed. I felt that quitting program in this case is too cruel, and didn't pay proper attention. Fixed

Comment: About your last point, I've seen it both ways. Is this a strict  mandate? I personally find it more intuitive that the `*` is bound to the type rather than the variable.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ No, there is no mandate. It is just more consistent. Consider however a declaration `int x, *y;`.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Concerning `-->  *` vs. `-->* `: the C spec uses `void *malloc(size_t size);`